# What do I do once a branch is marked as 'Needs Fixing'

Tags: launchpad, bazaar

I have a branch to be merged here:

https://code.launchpad.net/~headbangerkenny/ubuntuone-android-music/branch/+merge/71364

I got told what I needed to fix and did that, do I need to set anything else?

I can't find any kind of help on help.launchpad.net so I'm stuck

(It's probably something really really silly, but ya know!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your merge request, you need to leave a comment saying "I did what you asked, it's ready now". Then the person at the other end who is the maintainer (or is otherwise in charge of merge requests) will take a look and say "Yes, this is what we asked you to fix" or "Hey, can you go fix *this* differently?" etc, then they'll merge it in once they're satisfied that it's in good working order.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a comment saying that you've fixed the issue is usually enough. Especially with a new contributor, the reviewer is probably keeping an eye on the merge proposal. Though, you can manually push the merge proposal back into the review queue by changing its status. Different projects have their own internal work-flows.

"Needs fixing" is the result of the review. "Work in-progress" is the status of the merge request.

Near the top of the page, you should see:

[image: status: work in-progress]

Click on the yellow edit icon, and change the status back to "Needs review."

[image: needs review]